# How to protect against input arrays

Tags: php, security, get

I have a program. It accepts an input of a alphanumeric string (which I already do checks for).
So a valid input would be `www.example.com/myfile.php?input=John1`

However, if someone were to type in `www.example.com/myfile.php?input[]` then it breaks my entire program's logic breaks because I don't accept input as an array. How can I unsure the thing a user enters is just a string. Not an array, or any other data types/structures?

Comment: Use `if (!strpos("["))`

Comment: @Mohammad Sorry, can you give me an example?

Comment: Welcome. `www.example.com/myfile.php?input=John1` contains non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Something like https://3v4l.org/FWWY5

Comment: `if (is_string($_GET['input'])) {echo 'variable is a string';}`

Comment: @kerbholz Input contains an alphanumeric string??? What do you mean

Comment: @RolandStarke `is_string()` doesn't help. you can't detect string contain `[]` using this function

Comment: "_So a valid input would be www.example.com/myfile.php?input=John1_" sounds like `www.example.com/myfile.php?input=John1` is the valid input. Do you mean `John1` is a valid input?

Comment: What code breaks? Can you give us the code that runs instead of us trying to guess how to solve it?

Comment: @Mohammad My thought was instead of validating somewhere what url one can use, you should validate the param itself inside `myfile.php`.

Answer (score 0):

There is the slow and tedious way of solving this problem, which involves a lot of manual type-checking. Expect to wear your keyboard out writing `if (!is_string($foo))` conditions throughout your application.

Or you could use [Ionizer](https://github.com/paragonie/ionizer) which was designed for solving this exact problem.

```
<?php

use ParagonIE\Ionizer\GeneralFilterContainer;
use ParagonIE\Ionizer\Filter\{
    StringFilter,
    WhiteList
};

// Define properties to filter:
$ic = new GeneralFilterContainer();
$ic->addFilter(
        'username',
        (new StringFilter())->setPattern('^[A-Za-z0-9_\-]{3,24}$')
    )
    ->addFilter('passphrase', new StringFilter())
    ->addFilter(
        'domain',
        new WhiteList('US-1', 'US-2', 'EU-1', 'EU-2')
    );

// Invoke the filter container on the array to get the filtered result:
try {
    // $post passed all of our filters.
    $post = $ic($_POST);
} catch (\TypeError $ex) {
    // Invalid data provided.
}
```

If someone attempts to pass an array instead of a string, `$ic($_POST)` throws a `TypeError` which you can then catch, log, and fail gracefully.