# How to determine if something is not a string and if something is just empty?

Tags: php, string, get

In my php I have 2 optional inputs. `input1=` and `input2=`. Both are optional inputs. My question is how do I determine if an input was just not provided or if the input provided was not a string?

I only want people to put an actual string. Not different types of data structures.

Examples

Valid: `www.example.com/myfile.php?input1=hello&input2=bye`

Valid: `www.example.com/myfile.php?input1=hello`

Valid: `www.example.com/myfile.php?input2=hello`

Valid: `www.example.com/myfile.php`

Invalid: `www.example.com/myfile.php?input1[]`

---

```
<?php

function check_valid($string) {
    if (!is_string($string)) {
        echo "This is a not string. We tested: ".$string."<br>";
    } else {
        echo "This is is string. We tested: ".$string."<br>";
    }
}

$input1 = check_valid($_GET['input1']);
$input2 = check_valid($_GET['input2']);
?>
```

Comment: any set of characters can be interpreted as string ! To check if input was provided or not. use `empty()` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect against input arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697587/how-to-protect-against-input-arrays). This morning you said the question was answered. Again WHAT CODE ARE YOU USING?!

Comment: @Andreas The code is above.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the isset() method to check if $input1 or $input2 are provided or not.

```
function check_valid($test) {
    if (isset($test) && is_string($test)) {
        echo "Valid";
        return;
    }
    echo "Not Valid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value exists, containts empty or null.

```
<?php

function check_valid($string) {
    if (trim($string) == NULL OR trim($string) == "") { //Will check if value without a space is null or empty         
        return "valid";

    } 
} 
$input1 = check_valid($_GET['input1']);
$input2 = check_valid($_GET['input2']);
?>
```